# Adding MP3 as Ringtone Android Write error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

I am getting a write error when trying to add a sound as a ringtone in my app.
I've tried different things but keep getting different errors. Not sure what to do.

The mp3s are passed into sound as URLS example:

```
sound = {"http://www.sound.com/file.mp3"}



 public void setRingToneInApp() {

        File k = new File(sound[+position]); // path is a file to /sdcard/media/ringtone
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Annoying Sound");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
        Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Log.i("", "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT=" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
            if (Settings.System.canWrite(context)) {
                Log.i("", "Settings.System.canWrite=true");
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context.getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
            } else {
                Log.i("", "try to get write permissin from user");
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context.getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
            }
        }
    }
```

The logcat shows:

```
.893 20546-20546/oidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: 20546
                                                                             java.lang.SecurityException: t granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
                                                                                 at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
                                                                                 at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                                 at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
                                                                                 at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1567)
                                                                                 at android.provider.Settings$System.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1938)
                                                                                 at android.media.RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(RingtoneManager.java:666)
                                                                                 at ListAdapter.setRingToneInApp(CustomListAdapter.java:257)
                                                                                 at ListAdapter$3.onClick(CustomListAdapter.java:101)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
08-24 15:02:57.893 1583-1751/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity ctivity
08-24 15:02:57.896 1583-1751/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity ctivity
08-24 15:02:57.896 1583-1751/? W/ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{22c90f8 u0 ctivity t132 f}
08-24 15:02:57.943 1583-14442/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-24 15:02:57.943 1583-14442/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
08-24 15:02:57.943 1583-14442/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-24 15:02:57.943 1583-14442/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
08-24 15:02:57.960 1583-14442/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9cb7fee0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-24 15:02:58.003 1583-14442/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9cb7fee0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8bbe9730)
08-24 15:02:58.015 1583-14442/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9cb7fee0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8bbe9730)
08-24 15:02:58.396 1583-1596/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{22c90f8 u0 ctivity t132 f}
08-24 15:02:58.406 1303-1340/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 2650112
08-24 15:02:58.431 1303-1303/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1303: eglCreateSyncKHR(1901): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
08-24 15:02:58.613 16409-20813/? D/Index: Indexing locale 'en_US' took 24 millis
```

Edit:

I also have this in the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First about the Exception you got for security.

To Use `WRITE_SETTINGS`

First it should be present in the manifest file.

Second You should call  `Setting.System.canWrite()` it return true or false based on whether you are allowed to write or not.

Third if the `canWrite()` returns `false` start [`ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS). In this case user will allow the persmssions to write.

Now for Ringtone, You can save the Ringtone in your Phone Memory and you can then make it a ringtone. This is as follow:

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myfoldername/dir3");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, myringtonename + ".mp3");
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
setringtone(file);
```

and then you can call your funtion to set it as ringtone

```
private void setringtone(File file) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "You");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,newUri);

        }
```

I hope it helps.